# Select only unique rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, unique

I want to select only rows that are unique according to the column userid from a mysql table. So if I have two rows with the same userid none of them gets selected but if its only one it gets selected.

I use the following code:

```
SELECT T.id,T.name,T.userid FROM tbltest T WHERE userid NOT IN (SELECT userid FROM tbltest WHERE tbltest.id<>T.id);
```

Is this the fastest way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

How is this

```
SELECT T.id,T.name,T.userid 
FROM tbltest T 
GROUP BY T.userid
HAVING COUNT(T.userid) = 1;
```

Comment: Errr surely you don't need the NOT IN?

Comment: Probably not, but all I did was add the GROUP BY and HAVING to the statement he posted.

Comment: I don't think this will work. Not a MySQL user, but doesn't GROUP BY have to list all columns that aren't aggregated? Most RDBMSs do...

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT T.id, T.name, T.userid, count(*) AS count FROM tbltest GROUP BY T.userid HAVING count = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's the fastest way... you could try:

```
SELECT T.id, T.name, T.userid, COUNT(*) AS num 
FROM tbltest T GROUP BY T.userid HAVING num = 1
```

Or

```
SELECT T.id, T.name, T.userid, COUNT(*) AS num FROM tbltest T
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM tbltest T2 WHERE T2.userid = T.userid AND T2.id != T.id)
```